# Separated Ethereum VM

Tags: evm

I'm trying to figure out if anyone has separated out the Ethereum VM for experimentation. It would be interesting to play with the interface to the EVM for smart contract testing without all of the other trappings of Ethereum.

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest looking at pyethereum https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum the pieces are all there. There's also https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-vm which is a javascript implementation.

Comment: There is also [EVM JIT](https://github.com/ethereum/evmjit) project that implements Ethereum Virtual Machine.

Comment: @PawełBylica it's ok to add another answer :-)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @dbryson's answer, there's [Masala](https://github.com/slpopejoy/masala), a standalone EVM written in Haskell.